# Best practise for self reassignment of PHP variable

Tags: php

My code where I redefine `$finalText` with itself produces a warning/notice in Netbeans and it made me wonder whether there is not a better way of doing this?

The warning:

```
You should use only:
1 assignment(s) (4 used)
to a variable:
$finalText
to avoid accidentally overwriting it and make your code easier to read.
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

My code:

```
$languageCode = 'en';
$finalText = 'Very large text with myLeftSquareBracket variables in it to be replaced later.';
$finalText = $this->applyFormatting($finalText, $languageCode);
$finalText = str_replace('myLeftSquareBracket', '[', $finalText);
```

Comment: Personally I would leave it now like this, if you put it all together into 1 line, that would be far too long for my personal taste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$finalText = str_replace('myLeftSquareBracket', '[', $this->applyFormatting('Very large text with myLeftSquareBracket variables in it to be replaced later.', $languageCode));
```

But as stated in the comments, this becomes less readable.

Or another solution is to use several different variables names:

```
$languageCode = 'en';
$finalText1 = 'Very large text with myLeftSquareBracket variables in it to be replaced later.';
$finalText2 = $this->applyFormatting($finalText1, $languageCode);
$finalText3 = str_replace('myLeftSquareBracket', '[', $finalText2);
unset($finalText1, $finalText2);
```

But is it really useful?

My advice is to leave it like this.